# Что такое LLVM?

Tags: llvm

Что такое LLVM?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Это виртуальная машина. Она включает в себя:

1. набор инструкций для построения байт-кода
2. набор средств для генерации байт-кода
3. набор средств для исполнения байт-кода

Чтобы попробовать llvm на *Ubuntu*, можно собрать и запустить простой пример sample.c.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("sample\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Сборка.

```
clang sample.c -S -emit-llvm
```

Файл sample.ll (с сокращениями).

```
; ModuleID = 'sample.bc'
target datalayout = "..."
target triple = "i386-linux-gnu"

@.str = private constant [7 x i8] c"sample\00", align 1 ; <[7 x i8]*> [#uses=1]

define i32 @main() nounwind {
entry:
  %0 = tail call i32 @puts(i8* getelementptr inbounds ([7 x i8]* @.str, i32 0, i32 0))
    nounwind ; <i32> [#uses=0]
  ret i32 0
}

declare i32 @puts(i8* nocapture) nounwind
```

Запуск.

```
clang sample.c -c -emit-llvm
lli sample.bc
```

Comment: Внести правку, пожалуйста, LLVM это не виртуальная машина. Выдержка из первого абзаца с официального веб-сайта: `Despite its name, LLVM has little to do with traditional virtual machines. The name "LLVM" itself is not an acronym; it is the full name of the project.`

Comment: Да и не `байткод` там конечно же, а `биткод`

Answer (score 4):

Хочу добавить к ответу что не только байт-код генерируется, но и компилируется в исполняемый машинный-код на почти все виды процессоров и на почти все виды ОС.

LLVM дает возможность выбирать в какой код генерировать.

LLVM генерирует промежуточный assembler подобный код для анализа того во что превратиться ваш высокоуровневый код написанный как на C, C++, Fortran, 
Ada и т.д.

Видел и JAVA, Python, Ruby т.е. LLVM дает возможность писать на чем хочешь, и на что хочешь получая очень высокоскоростной код, который еще можно оптимизировать на Assembler уровне.

Проект поддерживается такими гигантами как ... а вы и так из википедии дальше знаете.